# Subject import package difference

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, subject

I got a warning when I serve my Angular app.

```
depends on 'rxjs/internal/Subject'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

But when I changed Subject import package.The warning disappears. Here's my origin import

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
```

And I change to

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: You should never import anything from `/internal/`. `Subject` is imported only form `'rxjs'`.

Comment: As the path suggests, `/internal/` is reserved for internal purposes and must not be used to end user applications. You should use `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';`.

Comment: Thanks for suggests.Do you want to answer the question ,so I can give you the accept answer?